# add image after a label in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to have an image after my label.

Below is how I am trying to do.

```
<%= form.label :label, :class =>'col-sm-3' do %>
<%=image_tag "qun1.png",:height=>'20px',:width=>'20px',
:style=>"margin-left: 5px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 7px;
top: 23px;width: 37px;" %>
<% end %>
```

With this my label disappears and I can only see the image. What's wrong here?

Comment: why are you keeping label and image in do end block. you can separate it. you can write it without using do end block.

Comment: css in the views is not cool.

Comment: Hi Navin, Thanks It worked.

Comment: It would be great if you accept an answer or post another solution that worked. It's a q&a resource by the way, answers are also important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your `label_tag` and `image_tag`:

```
<%= label_tag :label, :class =>'col-sm-3' %>
<%= image_tag "qun1.png",:height=>'20px',:width=>'20px',
:style=>"margin-left: 5px;padding-left: 12px;padding-top: 7px;
top: 23px;width: 37px;" %>
```

Comment: class =>'col-sm-3', missing `'`